Keycloak Admin REST API getting 404 not found using Postman
I am using Keycloak latest version, where I have created a realm using Standard Flow running on port http://127.0.0.1:5001/. The admin UI is running as expected on http://127.0.0.1:5001/auth
The authentication process is working as expected,

Login to the client
Got the Auth token

Now I am trying to use Amin API to get all the users for that realm, where I am setting the base_admin_url = http://127.0.0.1:5001/admin/realms
When I am doing a request
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/admin/realms/FeteBird/users' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGc3j-VBOgrw'

http://127.0.0.1:5001/admin/realms/FeteBird/users Keep getting 404 response, however, the Bearer token is valid, I have not pasted the correct one here.


Do I need to set some permission to view users or other API end points? haven't found anything in this doc https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/latest/rest-api/index.html
If I turn on the authorization/authentication, the FE and post are not working because I have set as Authorization code flow, same goes with angular FE application.



You need to have view-users role to query all user of the realm, if your case 404 not because of permission.

@ravthiru where do we configure view-users ?? Since I have set Authentication flow as Standard flow.

Login user need to have view-users role, but your error is different i.e 404 , which is not related to permission. if it is permission issue you should have got 403

Can you please try this , I am using the exact same curl command and see my users
curl -X GET 
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/xxx/users 
-H 'Authorization: token 
-H 'cache-control: no-cache'
